# Filtering query results using combined columns

Tags: mysql, query

Not sure what this method might be called

I have a table

| Pupil | Payments | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PupilA | 100 | 100 |
| PupilB | 100 | 50 |
| PupilB | 100 | 0 |
| PupilC | 100 | 20 |

I am running a query as follows

```
SELECT Pupil, SUM(Payments), (SUM(Price) - SUM(Payments)) AS Balance , SUM(Price) 
FROM LessonSchedule
Group by Pupil Order By Balance Desc
```

Which gives

| Pupil | Payments | Price | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PupilB | 200 | 50 | 150 |
| PupilC | 20 | 100 | 80 |
| PupilA | 100 | 100 | 0 |

The problem I have with this query is that it gives all pupils, even if there is no outstanding balance.

I am looking to find a way to display only the pupils who have an outstanding balance

the desired result would look like

| Pupil | Payments | Price | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PupilB | 200 | 50 | 150 |
| PupilC | 20 | 100 | 80 |

Something like

```
SELECT Pupil, SUM(Payments), (SUM(Price) - SUM(Payments)) AS Balance , SUM(Price) 
FROM LessonSchedule
WHERE Balance !== 0
Group by Pupil 
Order By Balance Desc
```

I have tried `WHERE Balance !== 0` but as the `Balance` column does not exist in the column, the query does not work.

I have also tried  `WHERE (SUM(Price) - SUM(Payments)) !==0` but this gives the same result.

Is there a recommended way to achieve the desired result?

I have also tried `!=` in place of `!==`

Comment: (SQL questions belong on the sister site stackoverflow.com )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Pupil,
       SUM(Payments),
       (SUM(Price) - SUM(Payments)) AS Balance , 
       SUM(Price) 
   FROM LessonSchedule
   Group by Pupil 
   HAVING Balance != 0
   Order By Balance Desc
```

`WHERE` works after gathering the data, but before doing `GROUP BY`.
`HAVING` works after `GROUP BY`.

Since the `SUMs` (and other aggregates) are done by "group by", you must wait until later for checking `Balance`.

Note:  `Balance` is shorthand for `(SUM(Price) - SUM(Payments))` in your example, so `Balance` includes an aggregate.

Comment: That seems to do the trick... I will monitor it as I add more data and make sure it continues to work correctly.
You mentioned that, this may not be what I need... Is there much of a difference between `Where` and `Having`, it seems to do the same thing, bbut that is based on the limited entries I have

Comment: @PaulMcF87 - I explained further.